# How to write a file with sudo privileges in Python?

Tags: python, file, subprocess, sudo

I want to write content to a file with python. The file's location is in the root directory path: `/etc/hosts`

Below are the file permissions

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root
```

I want to update this file, and it can be only updated with **sudo**. So I have written the following script:

```
path = "/etc/hosts"
fr = open(path,'r')
b = fr.read()
b = b+'something to write'
fr.close()
fw = open(path,'w')
fw = os.system('echo %s|sudo -S python %s' % ('root', fw.write(b)))
```

But I'm getting permission denied error:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/etc/hosts'

I also tried with subprocess:

```
os.popen("sudo -S %s"%(open(path,'w')), 'w').write(admin_password)
```

But this again did not work.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: you should run the python script with sudo like `sudo python myscript.py`

Comment: you get the permission error already when trying to read.

Comment: My whole code is inside the same file, and I'm not executing this with terminal :)

Comment: @Dschoni No file reading is done successfully but not writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked for me finally. I created a new file called `etcedit.py` which will write to the file.

```
os.system("echo %s| sudo -S python etcedit.py %s"  % ('rootpassword', 'host_name'))
```

My **etcedit.py** file

```
import os, subprocess
import sys
from sys import argv

def etc_update(host_name, *args):
    path = "/etc/hosts"
    host_name = host_name[0]
    fw = open(path,'w')
    fw.write(host_name)

etc_update(sys.argv[1:])
```

This works!

Answer (score -1):

Check **/etc/hosts** folder permission or **file** permission

Comment: That was given in the question. And this should be a comment if you didn't see it

Comment: I need sudo permission to write that file that's why I added os.system('echo %s|sudo -S python %s' % ('root', fw.write(b)))

Answer (score -1):

Your can rerun it script with sudo if it has not privilege.
pexpect module is needed.

For example:

```
import os
import pexpect
import sys
import argparse

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run as sudo!")
    parser.add_argument('-p', dest='privelege', action='store', help='also has rights')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return vars(args)

full_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
print("full_path = %s", full_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()
    if args.get('privelege') == None:
        #check if it has sudo privelege and if not rerun with it.
        child = pexpect.spawn("sh", logfile = sys.stdout)
        child.sendline("sudo python %s  -p root" % full_path)
        child.expect("assword", timeout = 100)
        child.logfile = None
        child.sendline("YOUR_PASSWORD")
        child.logfile_read = sys.stdout
    elif args.get('privelege') == 'root':
        #if it have root privelege do action
        path = "/etc/hosts"
        fr = open(path,'r')
        b = fr.read()
        b = b+'something to write'
        fr.close()
        fw = open(path,'w')
        fw.write(b)
        fw.close()
```

If script has no root privelege it run sh and than rerun self with sudo.